# I am unable to enroll Touch ID on my MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-id

After clicking on add finger and putting my password in the dialogue box, it automatically says failed before scanning the finger. I have tried resetting the SMC, running device in safe mode but none of them works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I like to make a brand new user account to see if it’s a user keychain or home folder issue or a software / hardware issue.

If that works, you know it’s a preference issue.

If that fails, make a backup and get a new clean OS running. Either installing to an external drive or erase the internal drive.

If that fails, you have a [hardware issue for support](https://locate.apple.com/) to work on.